# find instructor free times in mysql ph

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+ 
| user_id  | inst_id | date_start | date_end   | 
+------------+------------+------------+------------+ 
|  20      | 1       |1375344000  |1375351200  | 
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

it tried about 20 queries but couldn't come up with an idea to get inst_id result within any given range time.
for example i want to know which `inst_id` are available from  `2013-08-01 8:00` to `2013-08-01 10:00`

Comment: You should be using `DATETIME` instead of integers to store your dates.

Comment: Instead of TIMESTAMP store DATETIME in db.

Comment: You can use those but for the convenience of the user, use `datetime` instead.

Comment: @EswaraReddy `TIMESTAMP` should be fine, but this is a unix timestamp, which is different. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

The query will be

```
SELECT inst_id FROM table_name
WHERE date_start = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01 8:00') 
AND date_end = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01 10:00')
```

Comment: You're missing a 2, and you need to select dates between the range. Not just equal to the first or last value.

Comment: @Mike We can use range for a single column not between multiple columns, so here we have to match using equal to.

Comment: Hmm, that's true. Maybe the OP needs to clarify what he means by "available from some date to some other date" since there are two dates.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be something like this

```
$time_start = strtotime( '2013-08-01 8:00' );
$time_end = strtotime( '2013-08-01 10:00' );

$sql_query = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `time` > '.$time_start.' && `time` < '. $time_end .'; );
```

Also you could do it all in SQL query with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` command.

[UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php)