# How to check if selected date range is between another date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am in the situation where i want to match a date range with another date range, it might be simple but i am stuck at it.

Below is table structure

**Table - lifecycles**

- life_id
- life_start_date
- life_end_date

then a few records as below

```
1 - 07/23/2013 - 07/24/2013
2 - 07/15/2013 - 07/25/2015
3 - 03/10/2013 - 03/10/2014
```

Now i want to search these records by date range and want to see if some life exists in that range; e.g. i want to find the lives between 08/01/2013 - 01/01/2014

As expected result it should select the life#2 and life#3

How can this be done with MySQL query?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are the dates being stored as `VARCHAR` or `DATE`?

Comment: You will find answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395738/find-instructor-free-times-in-mysql-ph/

Comment: life#2 and life#3 are not between 08/01/2013 - 01/01/2014...... (life#2 ends in 2015!)

Comment: @jpotter92 field type is VARCHAR

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer I meant that life#2 and life#3 are still alive in the selected date range

Comment: **WHY ARE YOU STORING DATES AS VARCHAR?** *Please* read [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    lifecycles
WHERE
    str_to_date(life_start_date, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '2014-01-01' 
    AND str_to_date(life_end_date, '%m/%d/%Y') >= '2013-08-01';
```

Which basically means life hasn't started before the end of the range you are looking for, and life didn't end before the range start.

Since you keep dates in VARCHAR format, you need to use str_to_date function, which is bad since MySQL won't be able to utilize any possible indexes you have on start_date or end_date columns.

Comment: doesn't work! as i need to find if queried date range is between the life_start_date and life_end_date

Comment: Than I'm not sure I understand what you are trying. This gives you #2 and #3 as result, since they are alive at some point during the time specified.

Comment: Worked like a charm now!

Comment: No problem :) but I would still recommend switching to DATE type for storing dates instead of VARCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
SELECT SUM( IF( '2014-01-02' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date, 1, 0 ) ) AS from_exist,
       SUM( IF( '2014-02-12' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date, 1, 0 ) ) AS to_exist
FROM date_range
```

So based on the results you can check whether date is between existing date range or not.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to exclude lifes that are ended BEFORE 08/01/2013 and the ones that are not started AFTER 01/01/2014. This should work:

```
SELECT *
  FROM lifecycles as alive
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
         FROM lifecycles as dead
        WHERE dead.life_id = alive.life_id
          AND (str_to_date(life_start_date, '%m/%d/%Y') > '2014-01-01'
           OR str_to_date(life_end_date, '%m/%d/%Y') < '2013-08-01'))
```